# Room-conditions supercritical fluids?

Tags: physical-chemistry, phase, pressure

Are there any reasonably obtainable supercritical fluids that I could, say, run my hand through? Wikipedia makes it sound like there are plenty of room-temperature ones, but no room-*pressure* fluids.

Comment: It looks that indeed there are no such fluds. Helium has probably lowest critical pressure - over 2  atm.

Comment: I mean, 2 atm is survivable, so if there aren't any others, you could post that as an answer.

Comment: See also http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/268470/26969

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If exceeding the "[liquid–liquid critical point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(thermodynamics)#Mixtures:_liquid.E2.80.93liquid_critical_point)" for a solution suffices, then perhaps you could survive contact with [methane hydrate](http://petrowiki.org/Equilibrium_of_water_and_hydrocarbon_systems_with_hydrates) for a short while. Though He is supercritical at ~two atmospheres, running you hand through it would be a chilly experience at about 5 K.

Comment: The question asks for "supercritical" fluids.  So helium at 25 atm and 25 &deg;C qualifies.  It would feel exactly like a gas at those conditions, because supercritical fluids are just gasses.  There isn't really anything too exotic about them.

Answer (score 8):

As you can see on this [data page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_points_of_the_elements_%28data_page%29), helium-4 has critical pressure of 2.24 atm, but helium-3 has 1.13 atm - only slightly above atmospheric pressure. [Hyperbaric chambers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbaric_medicine#Hyperbaric_chambers) work with 1,3-1,5 atm, so you could try there.

There is, unfortunately, question if it makes sense, as you wouldn't notice any serious difference in properties between subcritical helium-3 and slightly above critical point in pressure, but so far above in temperature. It would still be lighter than air, for example.

I don't think that much higher pressure would be a huge problem - the highest pressure survived by human is supposedly 54 atm - so says [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_pressure), but I didn't find proof. If there is a compound with critical parameters sufficiently near standard, you could touch liquid-like, not gas-like supercritical fluid.

Ionic liquids have relatively low critical pressures (even only 14 bar), but too high crit. temperatures ([source](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ie0603058)). On the other hand ethane's crit. temp. is below 30°C, but pressure over 48 atm. Maybe there's sweet spot somewhere, but it would be still high pressure and may be quite hot or cold.

Answer (score 5):

Quick googling got me to $\ce{CF3Cl}$, that has cr.p. at $\pu{28.8^\circ C}$ / $\pu{38.6 bar}$. $\ce{C1}$-$\ce{C2}$ freons look to have critical point in $\pu{30 .. 60 bar}$ / $\pu{0 .. 100^\circ C}$ range, so some of them probably are survivable. However, some compounds of this class are used for general anesthesia, so $\ce{He/O2}$ mixture respirator would be required.

Answer (score 5):

A number of long carbon chain molecules with large numbers of fluoride atom, have $P_c < \pu{10 atm}$ and $T_c < \pu{1000 K}$. That is within the reach of a good bicycle pump and a burner. In particular [$\ce{C12F26}$](https://www.chemeo.com/cid/10-804-7/n-Perfluorododecane), [$\ce{C15H4F28O}$](https://www.chemeo.com/cid/75-143-0/1H,1H,15H-Octacosafluoro-1-pentadecanol.pdf) and [$\ce{C20F42}$](https://www.chemeo.com/cid/12-080-9/Perfluoroeicosane):

\begin{array}{lll}
&\ce{C12F26} &P_c = \pu{912 kPa} &T_c = \pu{417 K} \\ 
&\ce{C15H4F28O} &P_c = \pu{784 kPa} &T_c = \pu{701 K} \\
&\ce{C20F42} &P_c = \pu{463 kPa} &T_c = \pu{700 K}
\end{array}

The critical point of a fluid is determined by its van der Waals constants.
For a fluid to be critical at STP it needs these constants to have the values
$a = 25$ and $b = 0.003$ in SI units. The value of $b$ corresponds to a molecule with around 300 atoms, but the value of $a$ is outside the range of published compounds.

However, something compounds like $\ce{C100F202}$ could be critical at around ordinary pressure and an easily achievable temperature, i.e. it might be possible to get a critical fluid by heating some goop in an open saucepan. 
It also seems that fluorocarbons tend to be stable and inert, so they may be safe enough to handle.

@Diracology and @Floris provide an in depth exposition of the relationship between critical points and van der Waals constants in their answers to my Physics.SE question [Fluids with critical point at ordinary temperature and pressure](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/268470/fluids-with-critical-point-at-ordinary-temperature-and-pressure). Their answers with internet search of van der Waals constant data lead me to start looking at at large fluoroacarbons. The ones listed above are the largest I could find data for. It should be possible design more suitable molecules computationally. See [Computing van der Waals constants from molecular structure](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/55784/computing-van-der-waals-constants-from-molecular-structure).

Comment: C100F202 would be a Teflon oligimer