# Computing van der Waals constants from molecular structure

Tags: physical-chemistry, computational-chemistry, gas-laws

How can van der Waals constants be computed from molecular structure?

Is there software that already does this?

Is there software that can design a molecule with specified van der Waals constants?

This relates to the question
[Fluids with critical point at ordinary temperature and pressure](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/268470/fluids-with-critical-point-at-ordinary-temperature-and-pressure)

Comment: then I guess http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41345/room-conditions-supercritical-fluids is also related.